# Redirecting to a particular page in website when clicked on link shared from Mobile via Branch.io

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io

I have video sharing and content sharing enabled for my iOS application with Branch.io deeplinking. When I share my contents from mobile to social networks and any user clicks on the same link from desktop, I would like to redirect them to a particular page in website.How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here: this is accomplished via the `$desktop_url` link control parameter. You can read about how to use it [on this docs page](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/configuring-links/guide/#fallback-url-customization)